# LSTM model with multiple columns for prediction

Tags: python, numpy, lstm

I have the following code which creates a prediction model for stock price using the LSTM model. In this example, it uses only the `'Close'` column of the dataset for the prediction. I want to modify the code and **use multiple columns** including `'Open', 'Close','High','Low, 'Volume'` instead of only one.
Working with multi-dimensions NumPy array is confusing me. Can you please modify the following code properly to feed multiple columns? thx

(the code is borrowed from:https://www.askpython.com/python/examples/stock-price-prediction-python)

```py
    import yfinance as yf
    import numpy as np
    import pandas as pd
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    from keras.models import Sequential
    from keras.layers import Dense, LSTM
    import math
    from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler


    data=yf.download(tickers='AAPL',period="500d",interval="1d",auto_adjust = True)
    data = data['Close']    # here I wanna use all -> data[['Close','Open','Low','High','Volume']] 
    dataset= np.array(data)
    train_data = dataset[0:70 , : ]
    
    scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
    scaled_data = scaler.fit_transform(dataset.reshape(-1,1)) #I know this part should be modified

    #  Creating training data size : 70% of the data
    training_data_len = math.ceil(len(dataset) *.7)
    train_data = scaled_data[0:training_data_len  , : ]
    
    # Separating the data into x and y data
    history_points=60

    x_train_data=[]
    y_train_data =[]
    for i in range(history_points,len(train_data)):
        x_train_data=list(x_train_data)
        y_train_data=list(y_train_data)
        x_train_data.append(train_data[i-history_points:i,0]) 
        y_train_data.append(train_data[i,0])
    
     # Converting the training x and y values to numpy arrays
    x_train_data1, y_train_data1 = np.array(x_train_data), np.array(y_train_data)
     
     # Reshaping training s and y data to make the calculations easier
    x_train_data2 = np.reshape(x_train_data1, (x_train_data1.shape[0],x_train_data1.shape[1],1))

    # Building LSTM Model
    
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(LSTM(units=50, return_sequences=True,input_shape=(x_train_data2.shape[1],1)))
    model.add(LSTM(units=50, return_sequences=False))
    model.add(Dense(units=25))
    model.add(Dense(units=1))
    
    # Compiling the Model
    model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error')
    model.fit(x_train_data2, y_train_data1, batch_size=1, epochs=5)
    
    # Testing the model on testing data
    # Creating a dataset for testing
    test_data = scaled_data[training_data_len - 60: , : ]
    x_test = []
    y_test =  dataset[training_data_len : ]
    for i in range(60,len(test_data)):
        x_test.append(test_data[i-60:i,0])
     
    # Convert the values into arrays for easier computation
    x_test = np.array(x_test)
    x_test = np.reshape(x_test, (x_test.shape[0],x_test.shape[1],1))
     
    #  Making predictions on the testing data
    predictions = model.predict(x_test)
    predictions = scaler.inverse_transform(predictions)
    
    #%% Error calculation
    rmse=np.sqrt(np.mean(((predictions- y_test)**2)))
    print(rmse)
    
    train = data[:training_data_len]
    valid = data[training_data_len:]
     
    valid['Predictions'] = predictions
    plt.figure(figsize = (20,10),dpi=150)
    
    plt.title('Model')
    plt.xlabel('Date')
    plt.ylabel('Close')
     
    plt.plot(train['Close'])
    plt.plot(valid[['Close', 'Predictions']])
     
    plt.legend(['Train', 'Val', 'Predictions'], loc='lower right')
     
    plt.show()
```